# Is there a consumer grade wifi router that reports usage by IP or MAC address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Is there a consumer grade WiFi router that can report usage (IP packet counts or bandwidth used) by IP or MAC address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that some of them have this (for example my own TP-Link WR1043ND, which is quite new but certainly not pro/prosumer). See the example below how TP-Link shows this.

[image: TP Link usage stats]

In general, it appears that it strongly depends on your router brand and model/model series. If you switch to custom firmware, I'm also sure that [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) has usage statistics.

[image: DD-WRT usage stats]

So, I'd say that *some* of the consumer routers have usage statistics capabilities. You can check the websites of router vendors to download the manuals or to simulate the router's web interface to see if they fit your requirements. For example [this LinkSys web interface simulator](http://ui.linksys.com/) (thanks to @Iszi for pointing to this website).

Comment: Third-party firmwares aside, I'm pretty sure this is limited to fairly new and/or prosumer-grade routers. My Linksys EA6500, bought within the past year or so and using the most recent OEM firmware available, does not have this functionality. I've seen the feature available on the WRT1900AC though ($280 MSRP, available new for as low as $230 based on cursory Google search) and on a friend's ASUS router which I'm told was in the near-$200 price range.

Comment: I just bought an Apple Airport Extreme 802.11ac router, and it does not have this functionality either. Before posting this question, I'd also looked at the specs on Buffalo's Airstation Extreme AC 1750 dual band router, and nowhere did it indicate this was possible.

Comment: For Linksys routers, if you want an idea of what features are available on the router (which may not all be advertised), you can browse the router's web interface at http://ui.linksys.com. Some routers might not have the full UI available, though. (The one for EA6500 just had a run-through of the setup application.)

Comment: My TP-Link WR1043ND (about $ 50,- and about a year old) has this functionality. I was amazed to see that the Linksys EA series does not have this. Strange... I'll rephrase my answer that it strongly depends on brand and model/series.

Comment: @agtoever It looks to me like Belkin just brought the feature into the newer Linksys WRT models, (currently, only the WRT1900AC) when they started building them specifically to be "Open-Source Ready". I'm guessing they adapted it from DD-WRT to some degree, though the UI very much matches what's on higher-end EA-series routers.

Comment: @Doug; Apple's Airport Extreme routers do have this functionality, but the only way to get at it is with the old AirPort 6.x Utility that shipped with Snow Leopard.  They removed this feature from the Airport Utility starting with Lion but the Windows version still has it.  Unfortunately, the old Airport Utility does not work with the newest-gen 802.11ac routers.  God only knows why they removed this feature.